# Как сделать, чтобы не рушилаcь DOM?

Tags: html, dom, google-translate

http://translate.google.ru/translate перевод сайта. Как сделать, чтобы не рушилась DOM?

Переводчик добавляет везде к тексту `span` элементы, чтобы при наведении  показывался исходный текст и перевод, рушатся стили сайта.

Comment: Есть такие варианты

1) забить на это. Человек, который пользуется переводчиком, понимает, что это произойдет.

2) сохранить переведенную страницу и поработать со стилями. Добиться хорошего отображения. Если при добавлении рушиться дом, проверить, "а корректный ли он?".

Comment: "Забить" никак не получается. Может есть какой то плагин? Просто если ставить гаджет то все будет отлично, но там программно нельзя вызвать перевод. Нужна помощь...